# How does fontsize in Figma compare to Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, mobile-development, figma

I have made a design in Figma that I wanted to rebuild using Flutter.
I'm having a hard time choosing the right fontsize in Flutter that corresponds to the fontsize I
used in Figma.

For example in Figma I chose fontsize 144 for a title and it looked alright, but when I chose this fontsize for that title in Flutter, it looks way to big. So how do these fontsizes from Figma and Flutter compare?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, The figam and flutter sizes do not correspond. It applies to other tools like Sketch or AdobeXD. Your job as a developer is also to understand what ahas been made in figma or sketch or adobe XD to be able to show the proper size in flutter honestly.

Also personaly, I think Flutter is great because you don't really need a tool like Figma to right and do beautiful designs because of the feature hot reload. You can just - if you want to develop an app for personal use and it's not a part of a bigger project with designers in the team - use the hot reload feature to look directly how your app will look.

Comment: Tnx for the insight. I will just play around with hot reload then.